# regex match pattern in a string multiple times

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string "*&abc=123&**&defg=hh&*" and so on the pattern start and end is *&&* and I would like to have the following when I do regex.matches or regex.split

first match  = *&abc=123&*
2 match = *&defg=hh&*

appreciate any help

Comment: the pattern start and finish per pattern *&&*

Comment: Please try to use proper formatting. As it is, it's a little difficult to know exactly what you mean. There's also no instance of `&&` anywhere in that input string.

Answer (score 1):

```
&[0-9a-zA-Z]+=[0-9a-zA-Z]+&
```

You may need to change the [0-9a-zA-Z] depending on what characters you want to allow.

```
& matches the characters & literally
[0-9a-zA-Z]+ match a single character present in the list below
    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
    a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
    A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
= matches the character = literally
[0-9a-zA-Z]+ match a single character present in the list below
    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
    a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
    A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
& matches the characters & literally
```

Comment: Hi Rudy that did the trick :-) really appreciate that

Comment: @user1293971, if that worked out for you please mark it as the accepted answer.